Rotational speed using conservation of angular momentum
I know that angular momentum is conserved, but I don't know how to calculate the new speed of an object after it shrinks. Say you have a spinning object, then it shrinks, then how do you calculate the new spinning speed?

Try setting the angular momentum of the initial state equal to the angular momentum of the final state :) Do you know how to calculate angular momentum from moment of inertia and angular velocity?
